# Python: Speed-up Code for mixed Distribution

Tags: python, performance, distribution

i have the following function to return a "mixed distribution":

```
#M=[float]*k = Center Value of distribution,
#S=[float]*k = Standard deviations,
#P=[float]*k = probability for each value (Sum is 1.0)
#rng = Random number generator
#n = len of return array [float]*n
#return [float]*n

def mixed_normal(rng, n, M, S, P):
    #See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model
    idx = np.random.choice(len(M), p=P, replace=True, size=n)
    return np.fromiter((rng.normal(M[i], S[i]) for i in idx),dtype=np.float64)
```

which is called like:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
def mixed_normal_3(rng, n):
    data = [(-5, 0, 5), (1, 1, 1), (1/3, 1/3, 1/3)]
    return mixed_normal(rng, n, *data)
```

with `n=10**6`.

**But, the implementation is too slow! Currently it takes around 350s on my machine. I need to get it down to approx 30s.**

I consider changing

```
return np.fromiter((rng.normal(M[i], S[i]) for i in idx),dtype=np.float64)
```

from a "for-loop" to a "single numpy-call".

But, i can not come up with a working solution!

**Minimal working example**

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()

def mixed_normal(rng, n, M, S, P):
    #See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model
    idx = np.random.choice(len(M), p=P, replace=True, size=n) 
    # Needs to be optimized
    return np.fromiter((rng.normal(M[i], S[i]) for i in idx),dtype=np.float64)      

def mixed_normal_3(rng, n):
    data = [(-5, 0, 5), (1, 1, 1), (1/3, 1/3, 1/3)]
    return mixed_normal(rng, n, *data)
    
# [float]*(10**6) expected  
print( mixed_normal_3( rng , 10**6 ) );
```

Comment: Could you provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by 'pre-slicing' the lists, `M` and `S`:

```
def mixed_normal(rng, n, M, S, P):
    idx = np.array(np.random.choice(len(M), p=P, replace=True, size=n))    
    return rng.normal(np.array(M)[idx.astype(int)],np.array(S)[idx.astype(int)],n);
```

The lists, `M` and `S`, are expanded to size `n` by taking all elements according to the random indices generated in `idx` – where `idx` has size `n`:

```
M = [0,1,2]
idx = [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,2]
M[idx] = [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,2]
```

These 'expanded' lists are then passed to the RNG.

**This improved execution time from 350s down to 40s for my test-cases.**

Comment: Best solution based on `rng.normal()` function, To improve them you have to switch to another random generator